# get empty instead of repeated value in query

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

```
|num|id|name|prj|
| 1 | 1|abc | 1 |
| 2 | 1|efg | 1 |
| 3 | 1|cde | 1 |
| 4 | 2|zzz | 1 |
```

I want to run a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE prj=1 ORDER BY name
```

but printing out repeated values only once. I want to keep all the rows and I would like to do this at database level and not on the presentation layer (I know how to do it in php).

Desired result is

```
|num|id|name|prj|
| 1 | 1|abc | 1 |
| 3 |  |cde | 1 |
| 2 |  |efg | 1 |
| 4 | 2|zzz | 1 |
```

any hint on where to start from to build that query?

Comment: Is there a PK in your table ?

Comment: yes there is a pk that is an autoincrement value and is called "num" (not shown here)

Comment: So, the row having lowest `num` value for same values of `id` will be showing the `id` value; while the rest would show `null`, right ?

Comment: no, unfortunately that's not true. they will be ordered by "name" so the "num" can be mixed (if i add later something that in the ordering come first)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I have edited the question to reflect what you are asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a session variable to test if the previous ID is the same as the current ID:

```
SELECT num, IF(@lastid = id, '', @lastid := id) AS id, name, prj
FROM table
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @lastid := null) x
ORDER BY table.id, name
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95c95/3)

Note that you need to qualify `table.id`, because `ORDER BY` defaults to using the alias from the `SELECT` list if it's the same as a table column, and that would order the empty fields first.

Comment: very smart! That's what I was trying to get! Thank you for the help, Barmar!